# How can I fix these failed Perl tests?

Tags: perl

#### Make test fails

I'm attempting to build Perl 5.16.3. However, it's failing at the `make test` part.

```
Failed 2 tests out of 2246, 99.91% okay.
    ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t
    ../lib/h2ph.t
### Since not all tests were successful, you may want to run some of
### them individually and examine any diagnostic messages they produce.
### See the INSTALL document's section on "make test".
### You have a good chance to get more information by running
###   ./perl harness
### in the 't' directory since most (>=80%) of the tests succeeded.
### You may have to set your dynamic library search path,
### LD_LIBRARY_PATH, to point to the build directory:
###   setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH `pwd`; cd t; ./perl harness
###   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd t; ./perl harness
###   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`; cd t; ./perl harness
### for csh-style shells, like tcsh; or for traditional/modern
### Bourne-style shells, like bash, ksh, and zsh, respectively.
u=99.10  s=23.36  cu=7851.09  cs=326.70  scripts=2246  tests=528321
makefile:868: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

#### Troubleshoot with harness

I wasn't sure how to deal with the vagueness of `may have to set`, so I ignored it at first. Here is the output (the error is printed below).

```
$ cd t; ./perl harness ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ../lib/h2ph.t
../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ..
Dubious, test returned 154 (wstat 39424, 0x9a00)
Failed 154/1704 subtests
    (less 534 skipped subtests: 1016 okay)
../lib/h2ph.t ...................................
Failed 2/6 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t (Wstat: 39424 Tests: 1704 Failed: 154)
  Failed tests:  87, 89-94, 98, 100-105, 111, 113-118, 122
                124-129, 255, 257-262, 266, 268-273, 495
                497-502, 506, 508-513, 567, 569-574, 578
                580-585, 615, 617-622, 626, 628-633, 711
                713-718, 722, 724-729, 807, 809-814, 818
                820-825, 879, 881-886, 890, 892-897, 903
                905-910, 914, 916-921, 927, 929-934, 938
                940-945
  Non-zero exit status: 154
../lib/h2ph.t                                 (Wstat: 0 Tests: 6 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  5-6
Files=2, Tests=1710, 38 wallclock secs ( 3.60 usr  0.15 sys + 16.97 cusr  6.03 csys = 26.75 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Here is the error.

```
$ cd t; ./perl harness ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ../lib/h2ph.t
#   Failed test 'extract() for 'double_dir.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'x/w''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'x/w'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x/w' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'double_dir.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'x/w''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'x/w'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x/w' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/x'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.jar' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.jar' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.par' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.par' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.war' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.war' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.ear' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'y.ear' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '2'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'y/z''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'y/z'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y/z' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/y'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.jar' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.jar' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.par' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.par' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.ear' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.ear' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.war' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'

#   Failed test 'extract() for 'x.war' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.

#   Failed test 'Found correct number of output files ()'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 491.
#          got: '0'
#     expected: '1'

#   Failed test 'Found correct output file 'a''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 498.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test 'Output file '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out/a' exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 501.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir found'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 503.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir exists'
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 505.

#   Failed test 'Extract dir is expected '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out''
#   at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 507.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '/home/osmc/perl-5.16.3/perl-5.16.3/cpan/Archive-Extract/t/out'
# Looks like you failed 154 tests of 1704.
# Failed test 5 - preamble compiles at ../lib/h2ph.t line 49
#      got 'Illegal declaration of subroutine main::__has_include at _h2ph_pre.ph line 754.
# '
# expected /(?^:syntax OK$)/
# Failed test 6 - output free of warnings at ../lib/h2ph.t line 56
#      got "Illegal character in prototype for main::__has_include : STR at _h2ph_pre.ph line 754.\nCompilation failed in require at lib/h2ph.pht line 1.\nCompilation failed in require at -e line 1.\n"
# expected ""
```

I then tried again with `cd ..; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd); cd t; ./perl harness ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ../lib/h2ph.t`, but the same tests failed.

I'm building on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (based on Debian). How can I build Perl without the tests failing?

#### Investigating the source

I had a look at the [source code](http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.16.3.tar.gz) of the test, but I couldn't really understand it. For example, the first fail in the error states

```
Failed test 'extract() for 'double_dir.zip' reports success (PP: 0 Bin: 1)'
at t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 478.
```

In `../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t`, line 478 is

```
ok( $rv, "extract() for '$archive' reports success ($cfg)");
```

I can't really see what it's trying to test above this point. (The rest of this test is viewable [here](http://pastebin.com/Rn73bdeS).

I installed and then attempted to upgrade `Archive::Extract` via CPAN.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31444665/1944384), I attempted to persist with `make install` regardless, then upgrade `Archive::Extract` via CPAN. `make install` worked fine. (I was installing in parallel to my distribution's Perl, in `/opt` instead, so I had used `./Configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS -Dusethreads`.)

I then attempted to upgrade `Archive::Extract` via CPAN. The install was killed, then left some kind of dangling job, although the quoted pid did not exist. I followed the recommendations and attempted to upgrade CPAN itself, but that install was also killed. (This had the same output, but I'm out of words.)

```
osmc@osmc:/opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/bin$ ./perl -MCPAN -eshell
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install Archive::Extract
Reading '/home/osmc/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Reading '/home/osmc/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Sun, 19 Jul 2015 06:17:02 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.10) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.9800]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


......................................................Killed
osmc@osmc:/opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/bin$ ./perl -MCPAN -eshell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 13152).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/osmc/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y] y

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install CPAN
```

I'm not sure if relevant, but I've never really had CPAN working on this system, as per my comments to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208013/18887).

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this on Stack Overflow.  There are perl regulars there that build perl fairly often, I believe.

Comment: There's also [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/). ;)

Comment: U&L has a policy against cross-posting, so if you don't do it eventually someone else will.   I'd go for closing it vs. deleting because it is then still visible and someone could find your link to the other post.

Comment: This question was already created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384294/how-can-i-fix-these-failed-tests-when-building-perl

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Oops, I manually migrated (copy-pasted) then this question closed/migrated after. I've deleted the other version.

Comment: Time to dig into the test code, see what is being tested, and what is the text of the error message, otherwise we won't know what exactly we're trying to fix.

Comment: Could you run the tests in a verbose mode and show what tests are actually failing (and why).

Comment: @LenJaffe I actually did look at the source code, but couldn't make sense of it. I've edited this into the question, including the source code I looked at.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I'm not sure exactly what verbose mode it. I did get a lot more information from the test originally; I probably should have posted this in the question in the first place. I've edited it to include this information now.

Comment: The version you're trying to build is more than two years old. Have you checked if the problem still exists in the current version (5.22.0)?

Comment: @CalleDybedahl I need this version because I'm trying to build Logitech Media Center aka slimserver, which can only run on this version or earlier of perl. I haven't tried building the latest version.

Comment: Fair enough. Since you're aiming to run a particular piece of software, one slightly cheat-y but perfectly workable solution here is to see if the software in question uses the bits that had test failures. In your case, those are very well localized (the Archive::Extract module and the h2ph script), so it shouldn't be that hard to see if slimserver needs either. If it doesn't, you can just do `make install` and go on your merry way. As one of the summaries says, it's 99.91% OK.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl I was considering that, but wasn't exactly sure how to tell if it needed those parts. Were you suggesting to just go ahead and see if it worked, or was there a more formalised way of telling? (My concern was that something would fail, and I'd not be able to work out what caused it, or there'd be another issue down the track with an uncommon function.)

Comment: `h2ph` is rare enough I'd just ignore it. `fgrep -r "use Archive::Extract" .` in the slimserver source tree checks well enough for the other. I'd give it a shot, and if weird problems show up later I'd go back and look at these problems more carefully.

Comment: at this point, I usually start using the Perl debugger on the test program. I set breakpoints, and step into and through code.

Comment: Indeed. Run the tests individually with `perl -d` and try to determine whether their failure is due to something being wrong on your system that you really need to fix or the test being wrong. If it's the latter, just comment it out.

Comment: @LenJaffe Perl is totally new to me, so unfortunately this is way out my depth without a detailed explanation or tutorial.

Comment: @reinierpost I don't totally understand. By "run the tests individually" do you mean the `./perl harness` part? If so, `./perl -d harness` fails for me.

Comment: You can even run them without the  harness, if all is well.

Comment: @reinierpost Both with and without harness seems to fail. `$ ./perl -d ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ../lib/h2ph.t` gives `Can't locate perl5db.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/armv6l-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/site_perl/5.16.3 /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/5.16.3/armv6l-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/5.16.3 .). 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.` Perhaps it's trying to find default perl libraries instead of the ones I've just built?

Comment: That is strange. Try without the `-d` (you won;'t get the debugger).

Comment: @reinierpost `./perl ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t ../lib/h2ph.t` gives a slightly different error: `Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/armv6l-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/site_perl/5.16.3 /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/5.16.3/armv6l-linux-thread-multi /opt/perl-5.16.3-LMS/lib/5.16.3 .) at ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 7.` …

Comment: @reinierpost …`Undefined subroutine &main::rmtree called at ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 5.
END failed--call queue aborted at ../cpan/Archive-Extract/t/01_Archive-Extract.t line 7.`

Answer (score 1):

Since [Archive::Extract](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Extract) is on CPAN, one option you have is to do `make install` with the `perl` you just built, and then update to the latest version of `Archive::Extract`, and see if the test failures still exist.

If the failures persist, switch to the build directory for `Archive::Extract` and run the tests in debug mode:

```
$ perl -Iblib t\01_Archive-Extract.t 1
```

(You might want to save the output to a file).

From the looks of it, at least some of the failures are related to tests involving compressed tar files (gzip, xz, bzip etc). One possibility is that your `tar` and/or other command line utilities do not match what `Archive::Extract` expects.

The debug output should help pinpoint the problem. Please update your question with the debug output from running the tests. No need to use pastebin or similar services. No need to post source code of the module you are trying to install as it is available on CPAN.

Update: Installing a module from CPAN does not require using the CPAN shell.

Download the [latest tarball](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/Archive-Extract-0.76.tar.gz), extract it, and do:

```
$ wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/Archive-Extract-0.76.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf Archive-Extract-0.76.tar.gz
$ cd Archive-Extract-0.76
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ nmake
$ perl -Iblib t\1_Archive-Extract.t 1
```